# Add spaces before uppercase letters

Tags: strings, f#

I'm trying to convert some very simple C# string utility functions to F# as a learning exercise. Ignore the fact that the C# version is implemented as an extension method for the moment.

The function adds a blank space before any upper case letters (with the exception of the very first char) - so, `"ATestString"` becomes `"A Test String"`:

```
return string.Concat(str.Select(x => Char.IsUpper(x) ? " " + x : x.ToString())).TrimStart(' ');
```

My first pass using F#:

```
let padWithSpace str = 
    (str |> Seq.fold (fun acc elm -> if Char.IsUpper(elm) then acc + (sprintf " %c" <| elm) else acc + (string elm)) "").TrimStart([| ' ' |])
```

Is there a more concise, or more importantly, *idiomatic* way to do this in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.collect` is equivalent to `Select`+`Concat`.

```
let padWithSpace = 
    String.collect (fun c -> (if Char.IsUpper c then " " else "") + string c) 
    >> fun s -> s.TrimStart()
```

Comment: Ah function composition, never thought of that. Hence my status as newbie ;) I think I like this better.